# This loop is only matching once and ending. How do I return several matches?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have this array that searches for matches between two arrays. The problem is that it only returns one match and completes. I would like it to return all matches.

Does anyone know why this is only returning once?

```
var arr1 = $("li a");
var arr2 = $("input").attr('value').split(',');
$.each(arr1, function(i, val) {
  if ($.inArray($(val).html(), arr2) !== -1) {
    // alert('You got a match!')
  }
});
```

Relevant HTML code:

```
<input value="Bob Marley, Bob Hanson, Bob Smith" />
<li><a href=#">Bob Marley</a></li>
<li><a href=#">Jeff CookieMonster</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Bob Hanson</a></li>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML code.

Comment: Also, what's up with the tags?

Comment: But ... there is only one match ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spaces issue [untested]

```
"Bob Marley, Bob Hanson, Bob Smith" splitted by "," 


= [ "Bob Marley", "_Bob Hanson", "_Bob Smith" ]
```

Comment: Genius Pedro. Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks @Dogbert for fixing the layout.

Answer (score 1):

There is a space after the comas in yout input. 
So only the first value is found.

You have to trim the values after splitting the string.

[Trim string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript) for more information on how to trim.