# Knockout JS. Applying extenders to all observables within ViewModel?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Is there a way to set a global configuration for a ViewModel in KnockoutJS?

Two possible use-cases could be:

- Applying an extender to each observable inside of the ViewModel. For example, if I write a trim function like here: [Automatically trim whitespace from all observable values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745486/automatically-trim-whitespace-from-all-observable-values), how can I have it be applied to each observable?

Looking at the Knockout Validation Plugin source, I see that when creating a validatedObservable(), it's really grouping all of the sub fields into an observableArray() which it then traverses and applies `obj.extend({ validatable: true });`. Is creating such a loop the best way? Is the only other alternative writing code like `self.firstName = ko.observable().trimmed()`?

- Globally change the defaultEvent from "change" to "afterkeydown."

I see that I can use `<input data-bind="value: name, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />` but is there a way that I can apply this to each input programmatically or by default? Is **this** still the preferred solution: [How can I get Knockout JS to data-bind on keypress instead of lost-focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386311/how-can-i-get-knockout-js-to-data-bind-on-keypress-instead-of-lost-focus)

- Finally, is there an alternative way to fire an event on **both** change and keypress?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you want to handle multiple events, it would be best to use custom bindings:

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tkirda/KfnQ6/)**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.onChange = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // This will be called when the binding is first applied to an element
        // Set up any initial state, event handlers, etc. here
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var el = $(element);
        el.on({
            change: function () {
                value(el.val());
            },
            keyup: function () {
                value(el.val());
            }
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // This will be called once when the binding is first applied to an element,
        // and again whenever the associated observable changes value.
        // Update the DOM element based on the supplied values here.
    }
};

var model = {
    name: ko.observable('John')
};

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

Html:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="onChange: name, value: name" />
<div data-bind="text: name"></div>
```

Comment: Great. That makes sense, thanks. As for applying an extender to multiple observables, am I best off creating and then iterating over an observableArray?

Comment: Regarding extenders, sounds reasonable to iterate over them.