# trim whitespaces in observables

Tags: knockout.js

I need to trim all my observables. How to do that without the html binding?
I've tried [Automatically trim whitespace from all observable values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745486/automatically-trim-whitespace-from-all-observable-values) but it doesnt work for me.
I use knockout version 3.0.0 and i've used both latest chrome and latest ie.

```
<div class="editor-label">
    <b>Name: </b>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <input data-bind='value: name, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' placeholder="Enter name" /><br />
    <span style="font-weight:bold" data-bind="text: name"></span>
</div><br />

<div class="editor-label">
    <b>Age: </b>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <input data-bind='value: age, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' placeholder="Enter age" /><br />
    <span style="font-weight:bold" data-bind="text: age"></span>
</div>


ko.subscribable.fn.trimmed = function () {
    return ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return this().trim();
        },
        write: function (value) {
            this(value.trim());
            this.valueHasMutated();
        },
        owner: this
    });
};

if (!String.prototype.trim) {
    String.prototype.trim = function () { return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); };
}

var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable().extend({ required: true }).trimmed();
    self.age = ko.observable().extend({ required: true }).trimmed();
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Exception: Object doesn't support property or method 'trimmed'

Comment: What version of knockout are you using?

Comment: Also what browser are you using to test this?  http://jsfiddle.net/g9ezw/27/ uses knockout 3.1.0 and on Chrome 33.0.1750.154 appears to work fine for me.

Comment: @NathanFisher Your fiddle works on all versions of Knockout that i tested from 2.1.0 onwards

Comment: @NathanFisher You also need to be mindful of the call to `valueHasMutated`.  Since the trimmed function is added to subscribable, `this` in the write function could refer to a computed which doesn't have valueHasMutated function.  You should use notifySubscribers instead

Comment: Henrik, whilst I can't work out why your trimmed extension isn't found, the `ko.computed` has issues if your observable value is undefined or null.  `this().trim()` will throw an exception, as will `this(value.trim())`.

Comment: Are you using ViewModel as a constructor ie `var viewModel = new ViewModel()`

Comment: Updated my post. Im using knockout 3.0.0 and browsers i've tried is latest chrome and ie.

Comment: @RobertSlaney Thank you. That was correct. I added '' to the observables and now the trim working. But it only trims at beginning and end, i want all whitespaces to be removed. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Change your regex.  `^\s+` matches at the start, `\s+$` matches at the end.  Change it to just `/\s/g`

Comment: @NathanFisher Fix read when observable is undefined or null: 
`read: function () {  if (!this()) this('');  return this().trim();        }`