# ko.observable() trim ending whitespace

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation, extender

I have an HTML text input called hours that is verified as a number through a knockout extender. If the user entering the hours has any whitespace after the number they enter, I would like to simply have this trimmed without getting notified that what they've entered for hours is not a number. For example, if they enter "2.5   ", this should be correct as I want the extra spaces trimmed automatically. How am I able to do this with what I have below? Thank you.

```
hours: ko.observable().extend({ number: true, required: true })
```

Comment: Why not just make the input of type number --> input type="number". So that spaces will be ignored by default?

Comment: @CDA the Programmer, did my answer help you resolve your issue? if so, please mark it as accepted. If not, let me know and I'll try to help further.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a trimming functionality to observables, e.g. adding a custom function to `ko.subscribable.fn` as explained in another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745486/automatically-trim-whitespace-from-all-observable-values):

```js
ko.subscribable.fn.trimmed = function() {
    return ko.computed({
       read: function() {
           return this();
       },
       write: function(value) {
           this(value.trim());
           this.valueHasMutated();
       },
       owner: this
   }).extend({ notify: 'always' });
};
var vm = function () {
  this.num = ko.observable().trimmed().extend({ number: true });
  this.num(' 2 ');
}
ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout-validation/2.0.3/knockout.validation.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: num" />
```

P.S. Don't be tempted to add a `trim()` call into Knockout validator plugin `number` rule:

```
// this is the original 'number' rule implemetation, with a 'trim()' call added to it
ko.validation.rules['number'] = {
   validator: function (value, validate) {
        if (!validate) { return true; }
        return ko.validation.utils.isEmptyVal(value) || 
               (validate && /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)?(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(value.trim()));
    },
    message: 'Please enter a number.'
};
```

... because you don't want the trimming to happen during validation, but much earlier, that is: during the writing.