# Javascript - kill white space in front of string

Tags: javascript, string, space

I making some server reguests and the server reply me with a string that has a lot of spaces in front of the string. the string is USERNAME EXIST

I know how to use this:

```
String.prototype.killWhiteSpace = function() {
return this.replace(/\s/g, '');};

String.prototype.reduceWhiteSpace = function() {
return this.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');};
```

but the first the first answer me USERNAMEEXISTS and the second on " USERNAME EXIST"(with one space in front of the string).
Is there any way to kill all white spaces before and after the string?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `^` to match the start of a string and `$` to match the end of it in a regular expression:

```
String.prototype.killWhiteSpace = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, '');
};
```

Normally stripping whitespace is called [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)ming and is already implemented natively in modern browsers. So you may want to use this:

```
String.prototype.trim = String.prototype.trim || 
  function() {
      return this.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, '');
  };
```

Which will create a shim for [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) if it doesn't already exist, otherwise it will leave the native implementation (which is much faster) in place.

Answer (score 0):

String trimming is an interesting subject.  Some browsers can optimize certain regular expressions better than others.  Here's a good article: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-trim-javascript

I normally use the first method from that article:

```
String.prototype.killWhiteSpace = function() {
  return this.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
};
```

Note that this article (and this solution) focuses on performance. That may or may not be important to you, and other answers here will certainly fit the bill.