# Using Javascript, what is the method to get an element, based on the text between the opening and closing tags?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm a beginner, and couldn't find the answer after searching.

In my example, I'm looking for an

```
<a href="bla" onclick="dah">some text here</a>
```

I'd want to find this particular element, so I can do stuff with it.

Edit: The only thing I know that's unique about the element for sure, is the text "some text here", that's why I want to find it based on that.

Comment: Can you modify the element to add an `id` attribute?

Comment: There is no such a method in pure JavaScript. You'd have to implement a search yourself or use a library like jQuery (as suggested in some of the the answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put id on the element:

```
<a href="bla" onclick="dah" id='myEl'>some text here</a>
```

From javascript:

```
var myEl = document.getElementById('myEl') // gives the element
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use psuedo selector :contains, with the [jQuery library](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

Example 2

```
$('div:contains("test")').css('background-color', 'red');​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9z5du/

Example 2

```
<script>
    $("div:contains('John')").css("text-decoration", "underline");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the element is a link, you can first call [`getElementsByTagName` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) to narrow down your search:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

Then you have to iterate over the elements and test which one contains the next you are looking for:

```
var element = null;
for(var i = 0, l = elements.length; i < l; i++) {
    if(elements[i].innerHTML === 'some text here') {
        // found the element
        element = elements[i];
        break;
    } 
}

if(element) {
    // found the element, lets do something awesome with it
}
```

There are multiple ways to get the content of an element, using `Node#innerText` (IE) or `Node#textContent` (W3C) is another option. You might have to [trim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript) the text first before you compare it.

If the HTML is as shown in your post,

```
if(elements[i].firstChild || elements[i].firstChild.nodeValue)
```

is even more elegant.

The [MDN documentation about the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM) might be helpful.

If you can modify the HTML then adding an ID and using `getElementById` would be the better option.

Comment: I would use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` if you know you are matching text.

Comment: @styfle: That's another option, but for simplicity I wanted to avoid using `elements[i].textContent || elements[i].innerText`. If the HTML is as shown in the post `elements[i].firstChild.nodeValue` would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function getit()
{
  var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

  for(var i=0; i<elems.length; i++)
  {
     var text = elems[i].childNodes[0] != null ? elems[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue : '';

     if(text == "some text here")
       doSomethingWith(elems[i]);
  }
}
```