# JavaScript removing trailing white-space and periods from string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am attempting to remove all trailing white-space and periods from a string so that if I took either of the following examples:

```
var string = "  ..  bob is a string .";
```

or

```
var string = " .  bob is a string . ..";
```

They would end up as:

```
"bob is a string"
```

I know diddly squat about `regex` but I found a function to remove trailing white-space [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript):

```
str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
```

I tried modifying to include periods however it still only removes trailing white-space characters:

```
str.replace(/^[\s+\.]|[\s+\.]$/g, "");
```

Can anyone tell me how this is done and perhaps explain the regular expression used to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex is almost right, you just need to put the quantifier (`+`) outside of the character class (`[]`):

```
var str = " .  bob is a string . ..";
str.replace(/^[.\s]+|[.\s]+$/g, "");
//"bob is a string"
```

Comment: Thanks, why do you not need to escape the `.` character as I read `.` matches almost any character?

Comment: @GeorgeReith because the `.` is inside character class, so it means literally a `.`. Outside character class you would need to escape it. Just like the `+` you have in your regex doesn't mean a quantifier because it's inside a character class, otherwise you would have had to escape the `+` as well. Inside character class, you only need to escape characters special to character class, such as `]`, `^`, `-`, and  backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str = " .  bob is a string . ..";
var stripped = str.replace(/^[\s.]+|[\s.]+$/g,"");
```

Within character classes ([]) the `.` need not be escaped. This will remove any leading or trailing whitespaces and periods.