# how to simplify my conditional statement?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to simplify the following codes. The codes seem to redundant to me. Are there anyone here can help me out? Thanks a lot!

```
if(area.regionCode=='0' || area.regionCode==null){  

    var fakecode=area.region.substring(0, area.region.length - 1);
        area.region= fakecode +i;
}
```

Comment: How about empty string `''`? Is it `true` or `false`?

Comment: If the idea of the code is to update a counter on the end of the `area.region` value be careful about when you have more than ten of them such that the current number has two digits (your code would only update the last digit).

Comment: I think if those two explicit cases are what you're testing for, then this conditional logic is OK.  You could write a function eg called `isNullOrZero()` if you were really worried about the syntax.

Comment: see my answer now and let me know if i am lagging somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you think some code is not directly revealing, try giving it a new home with a suitable name:

```
if (!isValidRegionCode(area.regionCode)) {  
  ...
}

...

function isValidRegionCode(regionCode) {
  return area.regionCode != null && area.regionCode != '0';
}
```

It has more code overall, but makes your intentions clear.

Comment: +1 from me.  Also means the "definition" of what's a valid region code (in your example) is re-usable and maintainable at a single point in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend explicit condition checks. When using:

```
if (area.regionCode)  {   }
```

Style of logic, one is treating varAny as a boolean value. Therefore, JavaScript will perform an implicit conversion to a boolean value of whatever object type varAny is.

or

```
 if(Boolean(area.regionCode)){
        codes here;
    }
```

both will work same

returns false for the following,

- null
- undefined
- 0
- ""
- false.

beware returns true for string zero "0" and whitespace " ".

you can also first trim the output so `" "` issue will be solve 
here tutorial  [How do I trim a string in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript)

in the   @mttrb and @nnnnnn described case you can first convert string to either int or float by `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` check this [Converting strings to numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Converting_strings_to_numbers)

Comment: Should go without saying that you should be aware that this will also fire when `area.regionCode==false` which isn't strictly your original case, but that may not be a concern (or indeed, may be desirable).

Comment: This won't work. The number `0` is falsy, but the string `'0'` is truthy.

Comment: The string `'0'` is true not false.

Comment: all have good point ...please wait i have make it clear  by updating my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
if(parseInt(area.regionCode) > 0) {}
```