# Comparision of two equal strings returns false

Tags: javascript

Here is my line:

```
myArray[i].innerText == x
```

Here are the values from Chrome console:

myArray[i] = "13 ml Apollo glaze sherry truffel 250ml"

x =          "13 ml Apollo glaze sherry truffel 250ml"

myArray[i].innerText == x returns false
Why is this happening?

Here is how I define myArray:

```
myArray= $($('#myIframe').contents()).find('body#tinymce').find('p, li');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

debug it, you most likely have some extra whitespace characters in it.

```
console.log(escape(myArray[i].innerText));
```

You probably need to [trim it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript).

Or the HTML entities are there.

```
var replacedString = myArray[i].innerText.replace(/&nbsp;/g," ");
```

If you have a bunch of special characters, you will need to replace them all.

Comment: You were right. But I don't have extra space, but the first string has white space, and the second has "nbsp;". How to make the second string replace the nbsp with " " ?

Comment: Then the comparison returns false again.

Comment: escape(myArray[i].innerText) = "13%20ml%A0Apollo%20glaze%20sherry%20truffel%20250ml"

escape(escape(selectedText.replace(/&nbsp;/g," "))) = "13%20ml%20Apollo%20glaze%20sherry%20truffel%20250ml"

Comment: You do not want the escape in the actual comparison. Are you doing that?

Comment: @escaparello No. myArray[i].innerText = "13 ml Apollo glaze sherry truffel 250ml" and x = "13 ml Apollo glaze sherry truffel 250ml"
But before the comparison I make x.split("&nbsp;").join(' ')

Answer (score 1):

You aren't comparing two strings.

You are comparing a string with the `innerText` property of an identical string

```
myArray[i] === x
```

Comment: myArrey[i] is an HTMLParagraphElement

Comment: It doesn't return false when I construct [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/Bkrnu/) based on the code you provided.

Comment: If it is an HTMLParagraphElement, then its `innerText` property does not march the string you are testing against. Most likely there are differences in white space.

Comment: If I [change my example to use a paragraph](http://jsfiddle.net/Bkrnu/1/) then it stil works (only tested in Chrome).

Comment: But I don't define myArray on same way as you.

Comment: @Srcee — You added a bunch of information about how you were constructing it (not that 'it' is an array, it looks like a jQuery object) after I wrote my answer. Your current question doesn't provide all the information needed to reproduce the problem anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should compare `myArray[i]` rather than `myArray[i].innerText`, seeing as that is what you assign to. `myArray[i].innerText` will always yield `undefined`, if `myArray[i]` is a string (unless you're doing some weird prototyping).