# .trim js error in ie8, how can I fix it?

Tags: internet-explorer, trim

```
array[i].trim();
```

is giving an error but only in ie8

it gives an error about 'unsupported method'.

Maybe .trim was removed in IE 9 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.trim()` was added in 1.8.1 and was not implemented in IE8 or lower.

At the start of the code you can use

```
if(!String.prototype.trim) {
    String.prototype.trim = function () {
        return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
    };
}
```

and `.trim()` will be implemented for any strings.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming array is an array of strings, the JavaScript String Object does not have a trim() method. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp).

Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/498995/1660607) question you can do

```
array[i].replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
```

I hope that helps.