# How to parse data in javascript using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

How can I use regex in javascript to put items and its values in a array ?

This is my data sample:

```
battery.voltage: 13.50
battery.voltage.nominal: 12.0
beeper.status: enabled
device.type: ups
driver.name: blazer_ser
driver.parameter.pollinterval: 2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the below code to do that... here variable `data` contains your data...

```
data=data.split(/\n+/);
var output={};
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
     var a=data[i].split(/:\040+/);
     output[a[0]]=a[1];
}
```

These codes will give you an array like below...

```
Array ( 
    battery.voltage: "13.50",
    battery.voltage: "12.0",
    beeper.status: "enabled",
    device.type: "ups",
    driver.name: "blazer_ser",
    driver.parameter.pollinterval: "2"
)
```

Example:

```
output['driver.name'] === "blazer_ser"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use regular expression, you can simply use `substr` and `indexOf`. Assuming you have your list stored in an array you can simply loop through the entries and split on the first occurrence of a colon.

```
var items = [...]; // Your items.
var arr = {};
for (var i = items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var key = items[i].substr(0, items[i].indexOf(':'));
    var value = items[i].substr(items[i].indexOf(':') + 1).trim();
    arr[key] = value;
}
```

This solution will only work in browsers implementing the `trim` method. If you want to be on the save side you can overwrite the `String.prototype` and add the trim method. (See [Trim string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript))

If you have your items as a string separated by newlines you can easily split it into an array through `split`;

```
var list = "battery.voltage: 13.50\n"
         + "battery.voltage.nominal: 12.0\n"
         + "beeper.status: enabled\n"
         + "device.type: ups\n"
         + "driver.name: blazer_ser\n"
         + "driver.parameter.pollinterval: 2";​​
var items = list.split(/\n/);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hCYuP/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that makes only one pass through the string data using a single regex:

```
var list = "battery.voltage: 13.50\n"
         + "battery.voltage.nominal: 12.0\n"
         + "beeper.status: enabled\n"
         + "device.type: ups\n"
         + "driver.name: blazer_ser\n"
         + "driver.parameter.pollinterval: 2";


function parse(data) {
    var match, result = {};            
    var pattern = /\s*([^:\s]+)\s*:\s*([^:\s]+)$/gm; 
    while (match = pattern.exec(data)) {
        result[match[1]] = match[2];
    }
    return result;
}

var test = parse(list);

// dump array
for (var i in test) 
    console.log(i + ": " + test[i]);

// select one
console.log(test["driver.parameter.pollinterval"]);
```

[Click here to try it out on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johnrobinsn/Mm8A2/4/)