# Splitting text in JS by whitespaces

Tags: javascript, split, whitespace

I want to split a line of text by whitespaces (i.e. get rid of all whitespaces and leave the rest as separate elements). I have this code:

```
line.split(/\s+/);
```

but it doesn't work exactly how I want. For example `hi there!` it splits to: [hi,there!,] (notice 1 empty element at the end of the array). How to split a line without that last empty element?

Comment: Just trim the string first, and then do the split.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure there isn't an empty space at the end of your string? Cuz it's working for me.

In any case, try this:

```
line.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'').split(/\s+/);
```

This will remove any whitespace from the start and end of the string before splitting.

Comment: As i suspected the problem was in windows style EOL encoding. I didn't have spaces at the end of lane but `\r` formed the last 'empty' element. Anyway, your solution is universal (works both with windows and unix style encodings) so that's what I was looking for. Thx!

Comment: Just wondering - is there a reason why you use the `g` mod when using `^    $`? I'm probably misunderstanding the uses

Comment: If the string has spaces at the start and the end, these are two separate matches of the regex and both need replacing. Hence the need for `g`.

Comment: Ahh! Yes, I don't know why I didn't think of that logic. That makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

call .trim() before splitting the String, it will remove whitespaces before and after your String

Comment: `.trim()` is ES5 and [not yet fully supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

Comment: AFAIK javascript doesn't have a native implementation of `trim()` yet!

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski IE8 gets ES5-shim via conditional comment. Now, let's use the ES5 API, for goodness' sake `:P`

Comment: @bPratik [Sure it has](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.20) `:)`

Answer (score 2):

```
line.trim().split(/\s+/);
```

This should do what you want.

Comment: Fair enough. It has it in modern browsers though.

Comment: Sorry, just looked it up, should work on anything I want to use as a browser (and to hell with IE8) +1

Comment: A pretty good SO post on how to add it too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: @AndrewHubbs What do you mean? `.trim()` also handles leading space.

Comment: Thanks @ŠimeVidas. Didn't realize it did. Removing my initial comment.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to do

```
line.match(/\S+/g); // => ["hi", "there!"]
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not simply use

```
line.split(' ');
```

it splits "Hi there!" into

```
["hi", "there!"]
```

Comment: Because multiple consecutive whitespaces would result in empty array elements.

Comment: `"hi   there!".split(' ');  ["hi", "", "", "there!"]`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - ah yes, oversight on my part!