# jQuery - wrap all unwrapped text in p tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation where the following code is getting written to my page.

```
<div>
    Some text here which is not wrapped in tags
    <p>Some more text which is fine</p>
    <p>Blah blah another good line</p>
</div>
```

In this case it always seems to be the first line which is not being wrapped in p tags which might make the solution to this easier, although it's not every time. Some times it is fine.

What I need to do is identify whether the first line is wrapped or not and if not then wrap it.

Unfortunately I'm not sure where to start with this problem so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this code to wrap any TextNodes that are not wrapped with `<p>` tag.

```
function getTextNodesIn(node, includeWhitespaceNodes) {
    var textNodes = [], whitespace = /^\s*$/;

    function getTextNodes(node) {
        if (node.nodeType == 3) {
            if (includeWhitespaceNodes || !whitespace.test(node.nodeValue)) {
                textNodes.push(node);
            }
        } else {
            for (var i = 0, len = node.childNodes.length; i < len; ++i) {
                getTextNodes(node.childNodes[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    getTextNodes(node);
    return textNodes;
    }

    var textnodes = getTextNodesIn($("#demo")[0])​​​​;
    for(var i=0; i < textnodes.length; i++){
        if($(textnodes[i]).parent().is("#demo")){
            $(textnodes[i]).wrap("<p>");
        }
    }​
```

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/reWXX/2/) that shows this in action.

PS: TextNode detection part has been borrowed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4399718/205997)

Comment: Nice work! I added some CSS to make the result a bit clearer: http://jsfiddle.net/reWXX/2/

Comment: @OllyHodgson good work too :-) I will update the fiddle url in the answer.

Comment: @ArashMilani  i need the similar funtionality but this is not working for me ,probably in crome

Answer (score 4):

here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/RNt6A/

```
$('div').wrapInner('<p></p>');​​​​
$('div p > p').detach().insertAfter('div p');
```

Comment: I like this option, there's one small problem though. It's not always going to be a p tag. It could be pretty much any block level tag in fact. Is there as way of selecting `div p > blockleveltag`??

Answer (score 2):

Try this :-

```
<div class="container">
Some text here which is not wrapped in tags
<p>Some more text which is fine</p>
<p>Blah blah another good line</p>
</div>​
```

JS

```
    $(function(){
    var $temp = $('<div>');
    $('div.container p').each(function(){
            $(this).appendTo($temp);            
    });     

    if($.trim( $('div.container').html() ).length){
       var $pTag = $('<p>').html($('.container').html()); 
        $('div.container').html($pTag);
    }

    $('div.container').append($temp.html());
});
​
```

​Here is the working example :-

http://jsfiddle.net/dhMSN/12

Answer (score 1):

Ran into a similar need and attempted to employ the solution @Arash_Milani. Solution worked, however I ran into conflicts when the page also required to make ajax calls.

After a bit of digging, I found a fairly straight-forward solution on api.jquery.com using the `.contents()` method:

```js
$('.wrapper').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 3;
}).wrap('<p class="fixed"></p>').end();
```

```css
p.good {
  color: #09f;
}
p.fixed {
  color: #ff0000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  Some plain text not wrapped in any html element.
  <p class="good">This text is properly wrapped in a paragraph element.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is [bad at handling text nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery), so you'll need to do some direct DOM manipulation on this.  This also uses the ["trim" function.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/498995).  Its on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jNVF9/).

```
var d = $("div")[0];

for(var i=0; i<d.childNodes.length; i++) {
    if(d.childNodes[i].nodeType === 3 &&
       d.childNodes[i].textContent.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "")) {
        wrapNode(d.childNodes[i]);
    }
}

function wrapNode(node) {
    $(node).replaceWith("<h1>" + node.textContent + "</h1>");
}
```