# Is there a good reason for using the p tag for "just text" in HTML5?

Tags: css, html, article, paragraph

(Please advise me if I should take this question to another site, since it's theoretical.)

Consider the usual

```
<article class="faux-news">
    <h1>The zombies have arisen</h1>
    <p>Join our reporter as he unravels today's events from Reseda's Northridge Mall this morning.</p>
    <h2>Oh, the humanity!</h2>
    <p>Droves of humanity (living and undead) piled up on either side of the glass doors, one drove from the inside trying to get their filthy hands on some brainz and the other drove trying to get their meticulously manicured hands on the new iBerry. To the living, it was just another crowd to fight for their long since pre-loved tech gadget.</p>
    <h2>Un-undead Victorious</h2>
    <p>So strong were their desire for the mythical iBerry 6, so firm their resolve, that the living easily overcame the re-living. The stampede was too much for the undead, who were simply left for - dead.</p>
    <p>And so the living were spared infection by Zombie Rot on this day. But naturally, rumors are already in circulation about, primarily, the iBerry 7, and secondarily, iBerry 6 fans being zombies to begin with and how there's this big conspiracy bankrolled by the liberals and ancient aliens from Alpha Beta Six.</p>
</article>
```

vs.

```
<article class="faux-news">
    <h1>The zombies have arisen</h1>
    Join our reporter as he unravels today's events from Reseda's Northridge Mall this morning.
    <h2>Oh, the humanity!</h2>
    Droves of humanity (living and undead) piled up on either side of the glass doors, one drove from the inside trying to get their filthy hands on some brainz and the other drove trying to get their meticulously manicured hands on the new iBerry. To the living, it was just another crowd to fight for their long since pre-loved tech gadget.
    <h2>Un-undead Victorious</h2>
    So strong were their desire for the mythical iBerry 6, so firm their resolve, that the living easily overcame the re-living. The stampede was too much for the undead, who were simply left for - dead.<br>
    And so the living were spared infection by Zombie Rot on this day. But naturally, rumors are already in circulation about, primarily, the iBerry 7, and secondarily, iBerry 6 fans being zombies to begin with and how there's this big conspiracy bankrolled by the liberals and ancient aliens from Alpha Beta Six.
</article>
```

Which, if any, are the SEO punishments for **not** dividing the main text into paragraphs (rather than by some tag as divider)?

There could be styling problems for the `<br>`, but it could be replaced by `<span class="br">` or any stylable tag.

There could be styling problems targeting individual paragraphs, but this could also be solved - f.ex. with a `<p class="i-am-individual">` for just those.

Are there any other issues to consider - for example related to cross browser rendering? I don't see it, but you might see what I don't.

**In short**: *what are the hazards of skipping that pesky paragraph-izing text that can cause real amounts of work to fix unclosed `<p>` tags vs. "user usage of rich text editors"?*

Comment: OK..try and select each item of just-text and add bottom-margin. There's one!

Comment: In the question, I addressed the styling problems, explaining how to make a working example. You didn't think I'd have one? http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/yq39772wyflra5r/NoP.png

Answer (score 1):

The "hazards" are that you may have inconsistent styling for all the "just text" because you're relying on inherited styling wherever "just text" appears and it may appear in enclosing html tags other than `<article>`.

But this may be perfectly acceptable in your particular circumstances. 
Plus you'd gain a tiny bit by eliminating extraneous markup and from having to do all the work necessary to find and enclose "just text" in `<p>` tags.

Personally? I prefer having the text wrapped

Then there is this SO answer if you have the ability to use [**jQuery to wrap all unwrapped text in p tags**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836633/jquery-wrap-all-unwrapped-text-in-p-tags)