# How can I dynamically wrap elements in a div within another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following output of WordPress content:

```
<a href="#">link1</a>
text1
<br>
<br>
<a href="#">link2</a>
text2
<br>
<br>
<a href="#">link3</a>
text
<br>
<br>
<a href="#">link4</a>
text4
<br>
<br>
```

I DO NOT have access to edit the content so I'm looking to edit this via jQuery. I need to wrap each link with the text and br before next link in a div and then split it in two columns. So the final result would be something like this:

```
<div class="col-left">
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#">link1</a>
        text1
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#">link2</a>
        text2
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-right">
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#">link3</a>
        text3
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#">link4</a>
        text4
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any idea how can I achieve this using jQuery?

I have tried using .wrap() like this:

```
$('a').wrap( "<div class='item'></div>" );
```

Comment: Will there always be 4 items? Or will it be "half of all of the links on the page go in the first column, half in the second"?

Comment: No, the content is dynamic so it will be link5, link6, link7 and so on with its corresponding text

Comment: I'm tempted to say that your problem is too broad.  When I first read it I got the impression that you are looking for someone to code it for you.  I'd suggest formulating your question in a more specific manner.  Maybe break the puzzle up into simpler smaller puzzles and see if the community can assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a pretty fun challenge.

A quick explanation...
jQuery appears to struggle when getting text elements which aren't wrapped in any tag, so we must fist wrap them. I've used a `<span>`. I've used the code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836633/jquery-wrap-all-unwrapped-text-in-p-tags) to do that.

Now that they're all wrapped up nicely, we can select the elements we're interested in, and find the halfway point. If we have an odd number, let's call `Math.ceil`, so that the extra one ends up in the Left column.

```
var a = $('a');
var i = Math.ceil(a.length/2);
```

Now let's just get the first column and second column elements by calling [`$.slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/).

```
var firstColEls = a.slice(0,i);
var secondColEls = a.slice(i);
```

We can now loop through the elements and add the `<div>` with the `item` class. I'm using itemC1 and itemC2 so we can quickly select all the grouped elements later on. The class can have the same styling.

```
$.each(firstColEls, function(idx,el){
    $(el).nextUntil('a').addBack().wrapAll('<div class="itemC1"></div>');
});
$.each(secondColEls, function(idx,el){
    $(el).nextUntil('a').addBack().wrapAll('<div class="itemC2"></div>');
});
```

Now let's select the items, and wrap all of them (together) in the left/right column divs!

```
$('.itemC1').wrapAll('<div class="l"></div>');
$('.itemC2').wrapAll('<div class="r"></div>';
```

Wasn't that fun? :). [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/hhxzcubm/2).

Comment: Amazing! it wasn't that fun for me :) Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a variable like so:

```
if (check how many links) {
var wrapLinkLeft = $('<div class="col-left"><div class="item"><a href="#">link1<br><br></a></div></div>');
var wrapLinkRight = $('<div class="col-right"><div class="item"><a href="#">link2<br><br></a></div></div>');

 $(wrapLinkLeft).appendTo('body'); //for example append it to the body
 }
```

to make the link dynamic leave it empty and just append it to the href, which means you will probably need to set a class or ID for this href or build a counter to keep track of where the scripts at.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I could get.  It gives the desired outcome, but I'm not sure that it's terribly flexible.

```
var textNodes = $('a').first().parent().contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && $(this).text() !== "\n";
});
$(textNodes).each(function() {
    $(this).wrap('<span></span>');
});

var groups = $('a');
$(groups).each(function(index, item) {
    $(item).before('<div class="item"></div>');
    var theDiv = $(item).prev();
    var theItem = $(item).detach();
    var theRest = theDiv.nextUntil('a').detach();
    theDiv.append(theItem);
    theDiv.append(theRest);
    theDiv.find('span').contents().unwrap();
});

var theDivs = $('.item');
var half = theDivs.length / 2;

$(theDivs).first().before('<div class="col-left"></div><div class="col-right"></div>');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < half; i++)
{
    var nextDiv = $(theDivs[i]).detach();
    $('.col-left').append(nextDiv);
}
for (; i < theDivs.length; i++)
{
    var nextDiv = $(theDivs[i]).detach();
    $('.col-right').append(nextDiv);
}
```

And [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/8brrfb56/)'s the JSFiddle.  Cheers.