# Wrap text in table in p tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I could wrap text in the table cell, so it should change from `bar <code> bar` to `<p>bar <code> bar</p>`?

Here what I have currently:

([Link to jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bfrxhj8u/))

```
<style>
    table { width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; }
    td { border: 1px solid black; }
    td p { color: red; }
</style>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><p>foo <code>code</code> foo</p></td>
        <td>bar <code>code</code> bar</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('td').contents()
        .filter(function() {
            return (this.nodeType === 1 || this.nodeType === 3)
        })
        .wrap('<p />');
</script>
```

And so, the desired result should be:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><p>foo <code>code</code> foo</p></td>
        <td><p>bar <code>code</code> bar</p></td> <!-- fixed -->
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You also need to include in the question a description of how your current code fails, what it does wrong (or doesn't do at all).

Comment: @DavidThomas I've updated it. ("But currently, the each word in the right column...")

Comment: Hmm... No answers. Maybe I'm asking something too obvious?

Comment: Forgive me if this is a stupid question, but is there a reason you can't just fix the HTML source? Why is a jQuery solution needed?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Easily. I need to dynamically fix markup after it was converted from Markdown source. Example: If you write "list" in Markdown using empty lines between items, the each item will be rendered inside `<p>` tag. But if you try to create list without empty lines between items, there will be no `<p>` tags, it will be just `<li>Some text</li>`. And my goal is to resolve this inconsistency (in lists and tables).

Answer (score 0):

> Hmm... No answers. Maybe I'm asking something too obvious?

yup! you answered your question..

But here is a snippet if you are actually trying to split data into blocks:

```css
p {
  display: table-caption;
}
```

```html
<table border=1px>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>
        row11 row12 row13
      </p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>
        row21 <code>row22</code> row23
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No, it's totally not about my question, thanks though :) My goal is to change the right column of the table, so it should be the same as left column. Also I can't manually change HTML markup, it must me changed using JS/jQuery.

Comment: Ok I think I get it now. So, you might need to modify question @james. Let me see if I can give u a solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836633/jquery-wrap-all-unwrapped-text-in-p-tags seems like this can help you.

Comment: Thanks, yes, the linked question is very close to my task.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using only `.wrapInner()`

The .wrapInner() function can take any string or object that could be passed to the $() factory function to specify a DOM structure. This structure may be nested several levels deep, but should contain only one inmost element. The structure will be wrapped around the content of each of the elements in the set of matched elements.

In your case:

```js
 $('td').wrapInner('<p> <p/>');
```

```css
table { width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; }
td { border: 1px solid black; }
td p { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><p>foo <code>code</code> foo</p></td>
        <td>bar <code>code</code> bar</td>
        <td>foo <code>code</code> foo</td>
        <td>bar <code>code</code> bar</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The `.wrapInner()` works with element, class, id.

You can use css to change visual aspects like color, font-style and others

```js
$('.c').wrapInner('<p class = "p1"> <p/>');
$('#c1').wrapInner('<p class = "p2"> <p/>');
$('#c2').wrapInner('<p id = "p3"> <p/>');
```

```css
table { width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; }
    td { border: 1px solid black; }
    td .p1 { color: red; }
    td .p2 { color: blue;}
    td #p3 { color: blue; font-style: italic;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><p class = "p1" >foo <code>code</code> foo</p></td>
        <td class = "c">foo <code>code</code> foo</td>
        <td class = "c">bar <code>code</code> bar</td>
        <td id = "c1">bar <code>code</code> bar</td>
        <td id = "c2">foo <code>code</code> foo</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```