# Trim String on both ends using javascript

Tags: javascript, string, trim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I trim a string in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript)

I have below string which comes from ajax response

```
"\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\t\r\n\tERROR: Profile : NOT SUCCESS\nCODE        : 2\nCATEGORY    : TECHNICAL\nSEVERITY    : null\nENVIRONMENT : DEV\nAPPLICATION : DEV\nDESCRIPTION : Profile: INVOCATION UNHANDLED EXCEPTION [null]\nDESCRIPTION : Profile: [ServiceAttribute]\nDESCRIPTION : Profile: Instance ID = 20130108124231841\n\r\n\r\n"
```

I am using below code to trim the string on both ends.

> var text = originalRequest.responseText.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');

However it's removing \n in between message which is coming from ajax response.
What i would like to have in the end is

```
"ERROR: Profile : NOT SUCCESS
CODE        : 2
CATEGORY    : TECHNICAL
SEVERITY    : null
ENVIRONMENT : DEV
APPLICATION : DEV
DESCRIPTION : Profile: INVOCATION UNHANDLED EXCEPTION [null]
DESCRIPTION : Profile: [ServiceAttribute]
DESCRIPTION : Profile: Instance ID = 20130108124231841"
```

how do i get this? Trying different ways from past 1 hour :(

Comment: If you have JQuery, you could use [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/). But dont include JQuery just for this...

Comment: What you have should not modify the new-lines within the string; http://jsfiddle.net/dmwpb/ make sure you view the output in something that honours new lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `trim();`:

```
var s = "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\t\r\n\tERROR: Profile : NOT SUCCESS\nCODE        : 2\nCATEGORY    : TECHNICAL\nSEVERITY    : null\nENVIRONMENT : DEV\nAPPLICATION : DEV\nDESCRIPTION : Profile: INVOCATION UNHANDLED EXCEPTION [null]\nDESCRIPTION : Profile: [ServiceAttribute]\nDESCRIPTION : Profile: Instance ID = 20130108124231841\n\r\n\r\n";
console.log(s.trim());

"ERROR: Profile : NOT SUCCESS
CODE        : 2
CATEGORY    : TECHNICAL
SEVERITY    : null
ENVIRONMENT : DEV
APPLICATION : DEV
DESCRIPTION : Profile: INVOCATION UNHANDLED EXCEPTION [null]
DESCRIPTION : Profile: [ServiceAttribute]
DESCRIPTION : Profile: Instance ID = 20130108124231841"
```

If `trim()`'s not available (IE 8-), try this polyfill:

```
if(!String.prototype.trim) {
    String.prototype.trim = function () { 
        return this.replace(/^[\s\uFEFF]+|[\s\uFEFF]+$/g,'');
    });
}
```

Comment: trim doesn't work in all browsers (for ex, ie), so i recommend to use the [jQuery trim](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)

Comment: @lante It doesn't make sense to recommend jQuery just for that!

Comment: @Cerbrus According to MDN, `String.trim` uses exactly the same `replace` parameters as in OP's code. So, why would the result be different? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Comment: @lante: Added an alternative.

Comment: @Rikonator: In that case, It's not the OP's code that's causing the problem.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yup, OP's method works for me; http://jsfiddle.net/EYaZc/. I'd wager OP is using `document.write` or something to see the result...

Comment: @Rikonator: Yup, I see. Problem solved, I guess :P

Answer (score 1):

You can start with using native `replace()` twice (reformatted to see reg exp):

```
"\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\t\r\n\tERROR: Profile : NOT SUCCESS\nCODE        : 2\nCATEGORY    : TECHNICAL\nSEVERITY    : null\nENVIRONMENT : DEV\nAPPLICATION : DEV\nDESCRIPTION : Profile: INVOCATION UNHANDLED EXCEPTION [null]\nDESCRIPTION : Profile: [ServiceAttribute]\nDESCRIPTION : Profile: Instance ID = 20130108124231841\n\r\n\r\n"
     .replace(/^\s+/, "")
     .replace(/\s+$/, "")
```

gives:

```
ERROR: Profile : NOT SUCCESS
CODE        : 2
CATEGORY    : TECHNICAL
SEVERITY    : null
ENVIRONMENT : DEV
APPLICATION : DEV
DESCRIPTION : Profile: INVOCATION UNHANDLED EXCEPTION [null]
DESCRIPTION : Profile: [ServiceAttribute]
DESCRIPTION : Profile: Instance ID = 20130108124231841
```

Comment: I am still getting same message. it should keep the \n which comes in-between text or it should replace \n with proper enter(next line) in view

Comment: I use Windows 7 and I tried that in W7 on Google Chrome console. On other systems end of line character can be different so different reg exp can be needed. I would start with this. What message do you get?

Answer (score 1):

For some odd reason I don't really like regular expressions. Whenever possible I try to find other ways. For those sharing my opinion, here is pure JavaScript code to custom trim a string based on your list of characters:

```
function MyTrim(text) {
    //turn into a string in case it's other type:
    var result = text + "";

    //trim leading characters:
    while (result.length > 0 && IsWhiteSpace(result[0]))
        result = result.substr(1, result.length - 1);

    //trim trailing characters:
    while (result.length > 0 && IsWhiteSpace(result[result.length - 1]))
        result = result.substr(0, result.length - 1);

    return result;
}

function IsWhiteSpace(c) {
    return c == " " || c == "\r" || c == "\n" || c == "\t";
}
```

In your case:

```
var text = MyTrim(originalRequest.responseText);
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/p4qGv/).

Comment: @Cerbrus trivial to add, yeah.. you happen to know any native JS method that identifies character as whitespace?

Comment: I don't think there's a `String.isWhiteSpace` function. A check for `"\t"` should do the trick, though :P

Comment: I called this way var text = MyTrim(originalRequest.responseText);

but I am still getting the text as original text (atleast in IE debug) and in output page without enters. :(

Comment: @NitinGurram sorry, forgot to remove tab characters. Try now..

Comment: I think i need to replace \n with <br /> to get enter in output html. can you guide me with this? Only replace \n with <br /> when found in between string

Comment: @Nitin you can replace in the trimmed string then.

Comment: text = text.replace("\n","<br />"); will this do the job? Afraid, poor at js. anything to escape or special cares?

Comment: @NitinGurram You need the `replace` to be global. `text.replace(/\n/g, "<br />")` should do the trick. http://jsfiddle.net/EYaZc/1/