# The if statement doesnt work in my forloop

Tags: javascript

Currently I am working on Java script project.the project is for Checking the values selected from a UDDF file with the whole values in the UDDF file.But the if statement used for comparison is not working.I have put my code below

```
function parseUddf(){
var myArray=new Array("null","airportID","airportSiteNo","faaRgn","uddfVer","null","airportName","verificationDate",
"city","state","horizontalelevationdatum","horiAccuracy","elevAccuracy","orthoDatum","orthoAccuracy",
"magDec","verificationDate","airportOrthoElev","airportEllipsoidElev","airportElevationLoc",
"verificationDate","towerFloorOrthoElev","towerFloorEllipElev","verificationDate","arpLatitude","arpLongitude");
var selt=document.getElementById("textdis").value;
var x = document.getElementById("uddf").value;
x = x.split("@");
var x0 = x[0];
x0 = x0.split("|");
var j=x0.length;
alert(j);
for(var i=1;i<x0.length;i++){
        alert("selt="+selt.toString());
    if(selt.toString()==x0[i])
 {
          alert("success");
          alert("i="+i);
          alert(myArray[i]);
//document.getElementById("textdistitleid").value=myArray[i];
 break;
    }


    }
}
```

the UDDF file values are:

|FAI   |50219.A   |AAL |1.07|
|FAIRBANKS INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT                                       |1592011|
|FAIRBANKS                               |ALASKA                        |
|NAD83     |5 CM      |15 CM     |NAVD88    |25 CM          |
|-20.4|1592011|
|  439.0|  470.0|20R+3990|1592011|
|  529.0|       |       |
| 644854.4|-1475123.2|

I need your help

Comment: Do you have an example for the value of selt?

Comment: I have cleared the error. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `==` you can use .equals():

```
selt.toString().trim().equals(x0[i].trim())
```

You can get  your trim() function for javascript from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript)