# I need some javascript to remove only leading and trailing spaces on a string, but not spaces in between any other characters

Tags: javascript, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I trim a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript)

So....

```
"   steve   monkey   "
```

would become `"steve   monkey"`

and...

```
"   cheese charlie face   "
```

would become `"chesse charlie face"`

so basically take out all space characters that occur before the first non-space character, and also remove all space characters after the last non-space character, but don't remove any spaces in between. thanks!!!

right now i am just removing all spaces like below, but i learned we need to keep spaces in the middle... :(

```
$newPassword.val().split(" ").join("")
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 4):

Use trim():

```
var testString = "                 hello                   wold        ";
alert("The text:"+testString.trim()+"End here");
```

EDIT: As noted in the comments and in the other answer, this doesn't work in IE < 9.
The jquery option does work on all browsers:

```
$.trim(testString);
```

Thanks to Joseph and mplungjan for clearing that!

Comment: oh wow. how have i never used that??? thanks :)

Comment: You should point out that this is not supported in IE < 9

Comment: damn, we need to make it work in IE8+. is there a function that will work in IE8? thanks!

Comment: found it... $.trim(str) in jquery.

Answer (score 2):

JQuery (Seems you use that):

```
$.trim(str)
```

Works in all browsers

Please note that

```
Str.trim()
```

Does not work in IE8