# How do I split a string by whitespace and ignoring leading and trailing whitespace into an array of words using a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I typically use the following code in JavaScript to split a string by whitespace.

```
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.".split(/\s+/);
// ["The", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog."]
```

This of course works even when there are multiple whitespace characters between words.

```
"The  quick brown fox     jumps over the lazy   dog.".split(/\s+/);
// ["The", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog."]
```

The problem is when I have a string that has leading or trailing whitespace in which case the resulting array of strings will include an empty character at the beginning and/or end of the array.

```
"  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. ".split(/\s+/);
// ["", "The", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog.", ""]
```

It's a trivial task to eliminate such empty characters, but I'd rather take care of this within the regular expression if that's at all possible. Does anybody know what regular expression I could use to accomplish this goal?

Comment: Horses for courses. `split` is used to *split* a string, not *mutate* it. See [how to trim a string in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript).

Comment: unfortunately javascript doesnt support **lookbehind** and even if you had used **lookbehind**,there would be space in the first split

Comment: I never thought of it from that perspective. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: can't you do a trim() before the split?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

If you are more interested in the bits that are not whitespace, you can match the non-whitespace instead of splitting on whitespace.

```
"  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. ".match(/\S+/g);
```

Note that the following returns `null`:

```
"   ".match(/\S+/g)
```

So the best pattern to learn is:

```
str.match(/\S+/g) || []
```

Comment: Watch out, `'   '.match(/\S+/g)` returns `null` instead of `[]`!

Comment: I wonder whose solution is faster yours or @Josh 's (if we handle the [""] case).

Answer (score 51):

`"  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. ".trim().split(/\s+/);`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I actually was going to go this route until I remembered that it requires a browser that supports JavaScript 1.8. That's fine for a majority of our users, but we still support older browsers such as Internet Explorer 7 and 8 whose JavaScript engines don't include this functionality.

Comment: Watch out, `'    '.trim().split(/\s+/)` returns `[""]`!

Comment: I wonder whose solution is faster yours (if we handle the [""] case) or @kennebec 's

Answer (score 16):

Instead of splitting at whitespace sequences, you could match any non-whitespace sequences:

```
"  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. ".match(/\S+/g)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant as others code but very easy to understand:

```
    countWords(valOf)
    {
        newArr[];
        let str = valOf;
        let arr = str.split(" ");

        for (let index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) 
       {
           const element = arr[index];
           if(element)
           {
              newArr.push(element);
           }
       }
       const NumberOfWords = newArr.length;

       return NumberOfWords;
   }
```