# Javascript: Load multiple Images from split string url

Tags: javascript, string, image, split

What I did already is as user writes some text, script adds it to UTL and loads a picture under the text input box.

What I want to do more is to be able to split input text by space (ex. `A1369 A2453` should be sliced into two variables `A1369` and `A2453`) and use these two variables to load all the pictures below input box.

The string length has to be unlimited.

I have read and tried to understand javascript split function, but had no success using it yet.

Code that I have now below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
        var val = document.getElementById('imagename').value,
            src = 'http://s7ondemand6.scene7.com/is/image/MothercareASE/l' + val.toLowerCase() +'_1?&$dw_large_mc$&wid=1059&hei=1272',
            img = document.createElement('img');

        img.src = src;
parentElement.insertBefore(img, parentElement.firstChild);
    }
</script>
```

How do I add the splicing using the `String.prototype.split` function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14912502/how-do-i-split-a-string-by-whitespace-and-ignoring-leading-and-trailing-whitespa and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core of the problem is simple. You have to use `val.split(" ")` which creates array of strings. You can then do a loop and create image for every sub-string:

```
var values = val.split(" ");
for(var i=0, l=values.length; i<l; i++) {
   var url = 'http://s7ondemand6.scene7.com/is/image/MothercareASE/l' + values[i].toLowerCase() +'_1?&$dw_large_mc$&wid=1059&hei=1272';
   ... javascript to show image belongs here ...
}
```

I created full code example. I used functions to separate code in smaller chunks. I strongly advise you to do that too.

### Full code:

```js
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
  var val = document.getElementById('imagename').value;
  document.getElementById('imagename').value = "";
  // turn "XXX XXX" into ["XXX", "XXX]
  var vals = val.split(" ");

  for(var i=0,l=vals.length; i<l; i++) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = createImageUrl(vals[i]);
    addImage(img);
  }

}
/**
  This function adds image to the beginning of image list **/
function addImage(imageElm) {
  var container = document.getElementById("images");
  if(container.firstChild) {
    container.insertBefore(imageElm, container.firstChild);
  }
  else {
    container.appendChild(imageElm);
  }
}
/**
  This function generates correct image URL **/
function createImageUrl(ID) {
  return 'http://s7ondemand6.scene7.com/is/image/MothercareASE/l' + ID.toLowerCase() +'_1?&$dw_large_mc$&wid=1059&hei=1272';
}
```

```css
img {
  margin: 3px;
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="imagename" /><button id="btn">
Click to show.
</button>
<div id="images">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly and know I understand how to split a string into variables.