# How to split string by space only in middle of string using JS

Tags: javascript, string, split

Normal split works like this:

```
var a = " a @b c "
console.log(a.split(" "))
["", "a", "b", "c", ""]
```

But my expected output is: `[" a", "@b", "c "]` it is possible? And how?

Comment: @mplungjan He doesn't want to *ignore* the leading/trailing whitespace, though, he wants it in his output.

Comment: @ mplungjan It is not duplicate of what you mentioned. Should be reopened.

Comment: Apologies... Here is the link for reference anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14912502/how-do-i-split-a-string-by-whitespace-and-ignoring-leading-and-trailing-whitespa

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is to use a regular expression and require word boundaries before and after the space:

```js
var a = " a b c "
console.log(a.split(/\b \b/));
```

If non-word characters are allowed as well, you can use `match` instead - either match spaces at the beginning of the string, followed by non-spaces, or match non-spaces followed by spaces and the end of the string, or match non-spaces without restriction:

```js
const a = " foo @bar c "
console.log(
  a.match(/^ *\S+|\S+ *$|\S+/g)
);
```

Lookbehind is another option, but it's not supported enough to be reliable in production code yet.

Comment: What about string var a = " foo @bar c ", its not working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

How about

`a.split(/(?!^) (?!$)/)`

If there may be more than one space and lookbehinds are supported then

`a.split(/(?<!^ *) +(?! *$)/)`

Answer (score -3):

You can trim the string before the split, for example:

```js
var a = " a b c ";
a = a.trim();
console.log(a.split(" "));
```

**update**

i was wrong to read the expected output, the result of my suggested code it's:

["a", "b", "c"] and not [" a", "b", "c "]