# String.substr() returning entire string?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, substr

I'm writing an application that takes lyrics and formats them into Google Slides based on number of line breaks between stanzas. To keep the logic simple, I've been testing the same set of lyrics and finding the index of the word 'foo' and using that index to create a substring to push into an array. This array will be used to make slides in another function.

When I try to use the index of the word to do lyrics.substr(0, index), it returns the entire string, even with a valid index number.

```
function splitLyrics(lyrics) {
  var lyricsArray = []; 
  var lengthOfChunk = 0;
  var lengthOfSong = 0;
  var lyricsToPush;

  while (lyrics.length > 0) {
    Logger.log(lyrics);
    lengthOfSong = lyrics.length;
    lengthOfChunk = lyrics.indexOf('foo');
    Logger.log(lengthOfChunk);

    if (lengthOfChunk = -1) {
      lengthOfChunk = lengthOfSong;
    }

    lyricsToPush = lyrics.substr(0, lengthOfChunk);
    Logger.log(lyricsToPush);
    lyricsArray.push(lyricsToPush);

    lyrics = lyrics.substr(lengthOfChunk + 1);
  }

  return lyricsArray;
}
```

I expect the outputs of the logs to be "Original lyrics blah blah", the index number, and then "blah blah" or whatever substring output. Instead I get "Original lyrics blah blah", the index number, and then "Original lyrics blah blah"

Comment: Is it something here `lengthOfChunk = lyrics.indexOf('foo');`? You are looking for `'foo'` first occurrence. But lyrics has `'blah'`.

Comment: The lyrics were just an example. I use an actual word that exists in my actual huge string which contains lyrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A specific answer to your situation lies in the single `=` used for your equality check in the if statement. It is actually setting the value of `lengthOfChunk` to -1, meaning it is taking a `lyrics.substr(0)` which returns the full string.

However, it sounds like you can use `lyrics.split("[your word]")` instead of having to manually populate the array and move to the next string within the while loop. If I read the problem correctly, you could just:

```
splitLyrics = lyrics.split("foo");
```

This will get you an array of all strings not including the keyword.

Comment: Actually, what is much more elegant is this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14912552/11780044

Comment: Thanks! Still a bit curious about why the substring wouldn't return correctly, but this is definitely a far better solution to my problem that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: What was the index value of `lengthOfChunk`?

Comment: One thing that is buggy is the single `=` for the equality check of the `lengthOfChunk = -1`. That isn't acting as intended. Switch it to `==` to find equality of the stored value itself.