# How can i trim this javascript string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i trim this string in javascript/jquery

```
              £ 0.00
```

it has left and right white spaces, that i can simply remove with the trim() function but i want to remove this  `£` and get the 0.00 value.

Comment: For values that need to be manipulated, it's better not to have the currency symbol in the same string as the value. For example, if you are reading the value back from the DOM, then keep the symbol and the value in separate spans ... `<span>£</span><span id="whatever">0.00</span>`. Thus, you can simply get back to a number with eg `Number($("#whatever").text())`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I trim a string in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it always a pound symbol? Just replace it.

```
val = val.replace('£', ''); // then trim
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to replace all characters in a string except for digits and periods simply use a RegEx:

```
str = str.replace(/[^\d\.]/ig,"");
```

`/[^\d\.]/` matches all characters that aren't digits or `.`.

Answer (score 2):

> var str;
>
> str = str.trim();
>
> OR

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {

 String.prototype.trim = function() {

  return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');

 }

}
```

OR

str = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'')

Answer (score 1):

You could get that by using a substring and an indexOf functions

```
str = str.substring(str.indexOf(" "));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string.replace(/[^\d+(\.\d+)]?/g, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming something like:

```
var str = "              £ 0.00             ";
```

You have just to write your "custom" trim:

```
var number = str.replace(/^\D+|\D+$/g,"");
```

It basically trim from left and from right anything is not a number, and it stops when it found a number. Notice that you still have a string, if you need a real number you have use the unary operator (or `parseFloat`):

```
var number = +str.replace(/^\D+|\D+$/g,"");
```

Be aware that in case the string obtained is not a valid number, you will have `NaN` as result.