# Assign div text to variable then show it

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple task I'm trying to accomplish learning JavaScript but haven't been able to find a clear answer. Here's the code;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var show = document.getElementById("box");
document.write(show);
</script>


<div id="box">Testing</div>
```

Basically I want the text in the box div to be stored into a variable. Then, I want to display that variable's text on a different part of the page. With the code above I get a null error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/David_Knowles/LTfyH/

```
<script>
    var show = document.getElementById("box").innerHTML;
    document.write(show);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your JavaScript should find the element you address. Hence you need to put your `<script>` tag *after* the element is defined (this is one easy way).

Next, using [`.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) you can find element, but to get inner HTML out of it, you need to target [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML) property:

```
<div id="box">Testing</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var element = document.getElementById("box"),
        value = element.innerHTML;

    console.log(value);
</script>
```

Finally, for testing purposes you'd better use console. To make your script output values to the console, use [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console.log).

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is storing the ***DOM Object*** in the variable, not the text.
You should access the `innerHTML` property to access the text.

```
var t = document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML;
t = t.trim(); // to remove the whitespaces before and after the div.
document.write(t);
```

Comment: `String.trim()` is the feature for modern browsers only.

Comment: You can create a simple prototype function that bypass this issue.
See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript.

Comment: Ah, yes. Shim is the way to go.