# Checking if words match with or without spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a code, I'll just give a small example below. Though what it does is gets the users name, then checks for other context. Then I check them versus eachother, and my entire script works besides this one point and it's not giving a leeway.

```
  var getName= $('#element').text(),
      uName =getName.replace("Welcome ",""),
      loggedIn = newMember.replace(membersList,"");
         if(loggedIn !== uName) 
         {
          //run other codes
         }
```

Though when I do this it's still running the code. Am I writing the conditional wrong?

Comment: The conditional is fine, log the values to the console and see if they match, spaces and all. Using trim() could be a good idea.

Comment: If you want to pass data, put it in a *data-* attribute, not the content of a DOM element.

Comment: oh there is no data- attribute that I am using. And @adeneo nice to see you again lol. Anyways I'll log this and see what it comes out and can you tell me more about the .trim() I'll read up on it but a brief summary would be fine ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question title, I assume your concern is that the string comparison of `loggedIn !== uName` is being impacted by leading and/or trailing spaces on one or the other.

You need to use `trim()`, and would be wise to validate the presence of the prototype before using it (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8522376/1677912) for an explanation).

Your code would now be:

```
if(!String.prototype.trim) {  
  String.prototype.trim = function () {  
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');  
  };  
}

var getName= $('#element').text(),
    uName =getName.replace("Welcome ","").trim(),
    loggedIn = newMember.replace(membersList,"").trim();
      if(loggedIn !== uName) 
       {
        //run other codes
       }
```

Comment: Why thank you, I read the explanation as well. I will give this a go. Please wait for a response thank you.