# JavaScript remove leading and trailing spaces

Tags: javascript, replace

Here is a test:

```
console.log(" Golden Katana of the Unflinching Dawn                                    ".replace(/\s+/g,""))
```

I want to remove the extra spaces at the end of the string but it removes every space in the string, so how could I remove just the extra spaces at the end and just keep `Golden Katana of the Unflinching Dawn`?

Comment: Please have a look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try doing

```
trimmedstr = str.replace(/\s+$/, '');
```

or maybe

```
.replace(/ +$/, "");
```

Answer (score 28):

You can use `str.trim()` for this case. It removes the leading and trailing whitespace from a string. The regular expression `str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'')` will alternatively do the same thing.

Comment: I would just like to add that there are compatibility issues with IE8 browsers and below with using str.trim().

Comment: Good thing no one supports IE8 :D