# Remove whitespace of HTML form

Tags: html, css

I have this code that indents/whitespaces the content.

```
<form action="update-carousel.php" method="post">
```

How can I remove such indent/whitespace? I assume with CSS, but I do not know the tags to do so.

Comment: Are you currently styling it at all? If so, provide the CSS. More HTML might also be helpful.

Comment: I think you need to research your tech a bit. If there's unwanted indentation/white space, you'd need to remove it with JS prior to submitting the form.

Comment: What whitespace I am talking about is in the CSS styling of HTML <form> by default. Whistletoe provided just what I need to get rid of default margin/padding.

Comment: Note that you MUST do it in the css stylesheet, you can't do it on the form tag. Just seems to be how it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to remove margin and padding for the form-element, then use this in your css:

```
form {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Margin is whitespace external to the element and padding is internal.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use JavaScript (and/or do it on server-side).
This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript) will show you how to do it.

Note: CSS is for the design of your page, not for doing such operations.

Comment: Sorry but the user Whistletoe gave me what I was looking for.