# Search a table with js

Tags: javascript, html, search

I want to search a table in my html for a term. I have the code for that but it does not take alternatives like when I type in "what is that" it searches for "what is that" and not e.g. "What is that".

Also I want when I add a space at the end that the script ignores it and only goes for text chars.
 Here is the fiddle: jsfiddle.net/x7aUy/4
 Here is the code:

```
function doSearch() 
{
    var searchText = document.getElementById('searchTerm').value;
    var targetTable = document.getElementById('dataTable');
    var targetTableColCount;

    //Loop through table rows
    for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < targetTable.rows.length; rowIndex++) {
        var rowData = '';

        //Get column count from header row
        if (rowIndex == 0) {
        targetTableColCount = targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.length;
        continue; //do not execute further code for header row.
        }

        //Process data rows. (rowIndex >= 1)
        for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < targetTableColCount; colIndex++) {
            rowData += targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.item(colIndex).textContent;
            //if table rows = 0 then show no results text

            if (rowIndex <= 1)
            {
                document.getElementById('noresults').style.display = "block";
            }

        }

        //If search term is not found in row data
        //then hide the row, else show and hide no results text
        if (rowData.indexOf(searchText) == -1){
            targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'none';

        }           
        else {
            targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'table-row';
            document.getElementById('noresults').style.display = "none";
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/x7aUy/4/

Comment: You might want to check out [fullproof](http://reyesr.github.io/fullproof/)

Comment: already got the main problem solved, thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand, what you want is a non case-sensitive search ?

If yes, then just do a toLowerCase() on both of your data.

At this line :

```
if (rowData.indexOf(searchText) == -1){}
```

Just do

```
if (rowData.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) == -1){}
```

Then, 'searchString' will match 'searchstring' or 'SeaRCHsTRINg'

And if you want to remove the whitespace, juste add a regex filter on the input :

```
searchText = searchText.replace(/^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s)/g, "");
```

(Credits to [Regular expression for removing whitespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065807/regular-expression-for-removing-whitespaces) for this one)

Comment: thanks the first thing helped but the second not really :(    
I want the delete the white space in front and behind the entries.