# PHP Use Regex to match whitespace as well as empty characters

Tags: php, regex

I'll start off with some code, this is my current setup:

```
$search = [
  '/\{\{\sSTRING\s\}\}/is',
  '/\{\{STRING\}\}/is'
];

$replace = [
  '<b>TEST_STRING</b>',
  '<b>TEST_STRING</b>'    
];

echo preg_replace( $search, $replace, "{{STRING}}" );
```

This would then output **TEST_STRING**, as wanted, but I'm using two `REGEX` statements to make this  work, and I want this to work with strings like `{{ STRING }}` as well as `{{STRING}}` by only using a single `REGEX`.

I thought the statement would also ignore there being whitespace, but the `\s` statement specifically looks for anything relating to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`, is there an expression to use that will ignore whitespace as well as include it?

Comment: I think this would help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065807/regular-expression-for-removing-whitespaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an optional quantifier "?" after whitespace character "\s".

```
$search = '/\{\{\s?STRING\s?\}\}/is';

$replace = '<b>TEST_STRING</b>';

echo preg_replace( $search, $replace, "{{STRING}}" );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) Great knowledge to have.