# Check for empty space using javaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text box.

```
<input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey">
```

I want the user to prevent from entering empty space or tab or new line.Spaces between characters is allowed. How can I do that? Can some one give me a working demo? [I have this now](http://jsfiddle.net/2cYeu/)

Comment: Add event to input, pass `event` as parameter, then `if (event.which == 32 ...)`

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a **minimal understanding of the problem being solved.** Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: Can you even have a new line in an `input type="text"` field?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: have a look at my edited post.

Comment: @JavaBeginner your fiddle is working as expected.

Comment: I want to allow space between characters. For example,"Java Beginner" should be alowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add one more condition like

```
if (inputEl.value.length == 0) {
            if (e.keyCode == 32) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
```

**FYI:** *You can't have new line in TextBox*, so no need to prevent **`enter`** key

```
window.onload = function () {
    var inputEl = document.getElementById("nospace");
    inputEl.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
        if (inputEl.value.length == 0) {
            if (e.keyCode == 32) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2cYeu/9/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, spaces are allowed after if not the start of the string

```
window.onload = function () {
var inputEl = document.getElementById("nospace");
inputEl.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32 && this.value.length==0) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
}
http://jsfiddle.net/k6She/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
             $("#target").keypress(function(e) {
               if(e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode==32)
                   return false;

});
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I am checking the keycode of space bar and tab.Normally new line is not allowed in input type="text".

```
 window.onload = function () {
        var inputEl = document.getElementById("nospace");
        inputEl.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 32 || e.keyCode == 9) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    }
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2cYeu/)

***EDIT***: Try this: [Sample Code](http://jsfiddle.net/2cYeu/10/)

```
 $("#nospace").keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 32 || e.keyCode==9) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please note that spaces are allowed in between characters.

Answer (score 0):

[working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/USJws/)

HTML

```
<input>
```

Javascript

```
$("input").on("keydown", function (e) {
    return e.which !== 32;
});
```

This will allow all alphabets,letters,special characters except whitespace..

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rs6Gx/

Js:

```
$(function(){
    $("input").keyup(function(e){
         $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^\s/g, ""));
    });
});
```