# Javascript - Making Array Index toLowerCase() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, each

I'm trying to make all array indexes lowercase strings, but it's not working. I looked at other answers on here and tried their solutions like using `toString()` before adding `toLowerCase` but it doesn't work, which is weird.

I created a jsfiddle of the problem [here](https://jsfiddle.net/TheAmazingKnight/af91r2cq/5/).

JS:

```
$(colorArr).each(function(i, item) // loop thru each of elements in colorArr and make lowercase + trim
{
    if(colorArr[i] !== undefined) // check if colorArr index undefined
      {
      colorArr[i].toString().toLowerCase().trim(); // FIX HERE
      /* TRIED - DIDN'T WORK!
      colorArr[i].toLowerCase().trim();
      */
       }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why does the trim doesn't really trim? trim not working in my case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685076/why-does-the-trim-doesnt-really-trim-trim-not-working-in-my-case)

Comment: @juhana This is has nothing to do with `trim()` even though it's in the code, I'm asking only about `toLowerCase()`.

Comment: The solution is the same: you're applying toLowerCase and trim but not doing anything with the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i updated your fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/af91r2cq/6/

```
colorArr[i] = colorArr[i].toString().toLowerCase().trim(); // FIX HERE
```

your way was really close ;)

Comment: Comparing the other variable `checkedAttr`, why did it work for  `checkedAttr` instead of `colorArr` when both are array of strings?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the value back

It should be

```
colorArr[i] = colorArr[i].toString().toLowerCase().trim(); // FIX HERE
```

Or simply

```
colorArr = colorArr.map(function(value){ return value ? value.toLowerCase().trim() : ""; });
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way change all defined values in the array to lowercase is to use the `jQuery.map` function like so:

```
colorArr = $.map(colorArr, function(item, i) {
  if(item !== undefined) {
    return item.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
  }
});
```