# Remove extra spaces from left and right of a text

Tags: javascript, html, web

In my website, I have title that is kind of like this:

```
<title>Current Title &rarr; Sub Title &rarr; My Site</title>
```

I want to display the `Sub Title` part of the title in some of my html elements... so I wrote this JavaScript code to print the title, but only the text in between the 1st and 2nd `&rarr;`

```
&quot;<script>document.write(document.title.split("\u2192")[1]);</script>&quot;
```

But that code outputs `" Sub Title "` with a space in front and behind it. Do you know how I can somehow delete the 2 spaces using javascript (without changing the title) to output something like this: `"Sub Title"`?

Thanks!

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using JQuery trim over the one you have used already

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var titlePart = document.title.split("\u2192")[1];
    document.write($.trim(titlePart));
</script>
```

or if you want to stick to javascript, try using this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var titlePart = document.title.split("\u2192")[1];
    document.write(titlePart.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''));
</script>
```

Comment: Or just use `.trim()`

Comment: you can just use .trim() on your javascript variable and it will delete all the spaces