# How to remove space before and ending of text?

Tags: javascript, html

For example : I have a string like that: `" Text is text "`.

Now i want to use Javascript to remove all space before and ending of that string to have result :

`"Text is text"`.

How can I that with Javascript. Thank for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`String.trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) (IE 9+ and normal browsers).

`" my text ".trim(); // "my text"`

To make sure it will work in all browsers you can use a regular expression:

```
var str,
    re;
str = " my text ";
re = /^\s+|\s+$/g;

console.log(str.replace(re, ''));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/BmfBs/)

Comment: You mean `String.prototype.trim()`, `String.trim()` will give you TypeError.

Comment: I mean method `trim` of class `String`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use JavaScript built in function [`.trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).
It is not supported on IE 8 and below, however.

If you need to support older browsers, use jQuery [`.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = " Text is text ".

var res = text.replace(/(^(\s+)|(\s+)$)/g,function(spaces){ return spaces.replace(/\s/g,"");});

console.log(res);
```

Try this.

Answer (score 1):

Just try,

```
var str = " Text is text ";
str = str.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.trim()` spaces at the end and beginning , if you want unwanted spaces in between words u can use regex to remove that

```
" my text ".trim(); => "my text"
" my       text".replace("/ {2,}/g"," "); => "my text"
" my      text   ".trim().replace("/ {2,}/g"," "); => "my text"
```