# javascript regex white spaces before and after "sentence" need to be removed

Tags: javascript, regex, removing-whitespace

I need to remove all the white spaces before the first character (which is not a white space) and remove all the white spaces after the last character (which is not a white space).

Looks like this:

```
'                 a boat has an anchor       '
```

Should be `'a boat has an anchor'`

```
'   $$%&@$&$%& lollerskates #372734§     '
```

Should be `'$$%&@$&$%& lollerskates #372734§'`

Please ignore the single quotes, they are there to show the white space.

Comment: $.trim(' string with spaces at the ends ');

Comment: Wanted a regex solution if possible. I'm just not particularly great with regex.

Comment: @ShazboticusSShazbot: Did you add a reference to jQuery?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
string.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
```

Comment: What would it be if I wanted to remove all spaces that exist after the last character except for one (also keep the remove all white spaces before first character)... so it looks like 'bobby has a boat&nbsp;' <--wrote nbsp; because stackoverflow removes my white space

Comment: @ShazboticusSShazbot You could use `string.replace(/^\s+|(\s)\s+$/g, "$1");` or `string.replace(/^\s+|\s+(?=\s$)/g, "")` if you understand lookaheads.

Answer (score 6):

There is a native method for this. `string.trim`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

```
var orig = "   foo  ";

alert( orig.trim() );
```