# How can I remove trailing certain blocks of whitespaces from a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I need to adjust a string like so:

Cases where things should be adjusted:

```
Case a: "        ", becomes ""
Case b: "z       ", becomes "z"
Case c: "        z", becomes "z"
```

Cases where things shouldn't be adjusted:

<s>Case d: "   z   ", stays the same</s>

```
Case e: "zzz zz          zzz", stays the same
```

How can I achieve this in javascript?

Comment: You really want `" z "` to stay the same?

Comment: Sorry, no I don't, my mistake!

Comment: So case D is not valid? If so, use `string.trim()`.

Comment: And you may want to look through [all these other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+trim) on the topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `String.trim()` for this case. It removes the leading and trailing whitespace from a string. Many modern browsers support this method, which allows you to rewrite the above much shorter.

```
mystring = mystring.trim()
```

For browsers that do not support `String.trim()`, create your own method using a regular expression.

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
  String.prototype.trim = function() {
        return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
  }
}
```

Alternatively, for most cases using it directly will perform the same.

```
mystring.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')
```

See [`live demo`](http://regex101.com/r/qK8aY1)

Comment: This will not satisfy the Case d:

Comment: Sorry let's forget about case d.! This is working nicely however, it removes spaces in between my words, which I don't wnat. Any single space I'd like preserved. I.E 'I am a cool person"

Answer (score 3):

You should use the ES5 [`.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) method:

```
"        ".trim(); // "";
"z       ".trim(); // "z";
"       z".trim(); // "z";
"   z    ".trim(); // "z";
"zzz zz          zzz".trim(); // "zzz zz          zzz";
```

---

For compatibility with old browsers, you can add the following at the beginning of your script:

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
  };
}
```

Comment: This fails the totally weird preceding/trailing combo example, `' z '`.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by [Xander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88932/xander), try this, match all but variable e:

```
return s.replace(/^(\s+$|\w{1}\s+$|\s+\w{1}$|\s+\w{1}\s+$)/i, "Bingo");
```

And here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pyHLS/), hope this can help you :P

Answer (score 1):

Its enough for you to use `trim` function; but `string.trim();` wont work in all browsers...

Try this:

```
String.prototype.trim=function(){return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');};

String.prototype.ltrim=function(){return this.replace(/^\s+/,'');};

String.prototype.rtrim=function(){return this.replace(/\s+$/,'');};

String.prototype.fulltrim=function(){return this.replace(/(?:(?:^|\n)\s+|\s+(?:$|\n))/g,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ');};
```

Since new Browsers (IE9+) have `trim()` already implemented, you should only implement `trim()` if it is not already available on the Prototype-Object (overriding it is a huge performance hit). This is generally recommended when extending Native Objects! Note that the added property is enumerable unless you use ES5 `Object.defineProperty`!

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
   //code for trim
}
```

Comment: You could have said your answer is a perfect duplicate of [Pradeep Kumar Mishra](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22710/pradeep-kumar-mishra)'s [one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/498995/1529630).

Comment: Yes, its perfect, plus another sentense at the beginning.