# JavaScript / AJAX / Servlet compare Strings

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

I am trying to compare a string that is returned from servlet

Servlet page returns this:

```
out.println("pass");
```

JavaScript:

```
function Return() {
if (ajax.responseText === "pass") {
document.getElementById("pass").innerHTML = "This is valid number!";}
```

Now I have output the `("ajax.responseText")` and it returns "pass" but I can't still validate it in the IF statement.

I tried using `(.equal("pass")` i tried with `==` and I even tried `"var value = ajax.responseText;` and then tried `value === "pass")`

Yes I also tried `.toString()`..

It just never validates it correctly it always goes to ELSE statement...

Comment: Where is that function running? Do you have extra whitespace?

Comment: @SLaks thanks for editing my post, I am new to this website so I am still trying to figure out how to post proper ... I am trying to accomplish following. HTML page that takes users input on CREDIT CARD number. Now I am sending that info to bi validated in Servlet.. And I am sending back "Pass" or "Fail" STRING .. that is being checked in the JavaScript Function that will display Valid or Invalid in appropriate DIV tags

Comment: Regarding your edit: You also have to clear the content of the `#fail` element if the check is successful (and vice versa). Setting the content of `#pass` will *not* clear the content of `#fail`.

Comment: @LJ-C : If you have solved the issue, you can [post it as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @Pranav Thank you didn't know that, its my second post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`println` usually appends a line break at the end of the string (the "ln" in `println` stands for "line") and thus the string value returned by the server is actually `"print\n"` (or something similar), which is not equal to `"pass"`.

If available, use

```
out.print("pass");
```

which doesn't append a line break.

Or [trim the response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/498970/218196) before comparison.

Comment: Thanks... It was an improvement, however now it displays both for some reason :(

Comment: Then there might something wrong in the part of your code you didn't post. I cannot see an `else` statement for example. If you see both, then you probably haven't use `if...else` or used the wrong conditions for the `fail` case.

Comment: Resolved thanks.. I used 2 IF statements instead of IF...Else if

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your original function `Return` (which doesn't explicitly return)

```
function Return() { // Why not checkPassword?
  if (ajax.responseText === "pass") { // exactly equal
    document.getElementById("pass").innerHTML = "This is valid number!";
  }
}
```

Try something like this (e.g. presumably it should be `true` or `false`, so do so explicitly)...

```
function checkPassword() { // probably should pass arguments what the function does.
  if (ajax.responseText.trim() == "pass") { // trim the response string 
                                            // ('pass\n' != 'pass')
    console.log('Got a match!');            // Try logging it.
    document.getElementById("pass").innerHTML = "This is valid number!";
    return true; // return a value?
  } else {
    // Again, I would try adding some debug logging.
    console.log('Did not match! ' + ajax.responseText); 
  }
  return false; // default to false.
}
```