# jQuery TRIM space between 2 alphabets or words

Tags: php, jquery, trim

I want to remove white spaces at the beginning and end of the words. Also there should be just 1 character space between 2 words. I use below code but it only remove white spaces in the beginning of the first word and at the end. How can I remove extra space between 2 words.

**jQuery Trim**

```
var fullname= jQuery('#fullname').val();
    fullname= jQuery.trim(fullname);

if(fullname.length == 0) {
   var error = true;
   jQuery('#fullname_error').fadeIn(500);
   } else {
   jQuery('#fullname_error').fadeOut(500);
}
```

**PHP Trim**

```
 $fullname = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST["fullname"]));
```

Comment: both jquery and PHP trim function removes the while space from beginning and end of the string. Not sure what you are getting.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty yes now its working for beginning and ending white space, but is there a way to trim extra space between 2 words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use preg_replace()

```
preg_replace('/ {2,}/', ' ', $string);
```

this code will found any sequence of spaces longer than 2 and replace it by one space

upd: also you can use JavaScript native function replace:

```
string.replace(/ {2,}/, ' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to trim extra space between 2 words?

Yes.

```
var str = "foo    bar   etc";
str = $str.replace(/\b\s{2,}\b/g, ' ');
```

Or in PHP

```
$str = preg_replace('/\b\s{2,}\b/', ' ', $str);
```

Comment: I tried your PHP code but it removes all spaces between 2 words. I need atleast 1 character space. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here are String prototypes for trimming.

[String trim prototypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript?rq=1)

Include the following definition in your code.

```
String.prototype.fulltrim=function(){return this.replace(/(?:(?:^|\n)\s+|\s+(?:$|\n))/g,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ');};
```

Then use 'fulltrim' instead of 'trim' in your code.  'fulltrim' will remove spaces from the front, end, and the middle all at once.

Here is an example [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IFeFP3qEwwnHgK6Jc9mU)