# How to check for invalid argument in JS?

Tags: javascript, function

What can I do to attain the below thing... The argument generated is bit weird!

```
function function1(argument1,argument2)
{
if argument1 = "
") do something;
}
```

"argument1" and "argument2" are generated by the CMS. I can't do anything with those contents.

Either it will generate:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.write(function1("argument1","argument2"));
</script>
```

OR

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.write(function1("
","argument2"));
</script>
```

Comment: The second code is already invalid JavaScript and cannot be parsed. There is nothing you can do about it in JavaScript. You have to fix it on server side.

Comment: Hmm I can't do anything with that, its auto generated. Let me try some other way to attain the same.

Comment: The value might be autogenerated, but you it's you who builds the JavaScript code with it, right? I.e. you writing something like `function1("<% print argument 1 %>", ...)`. You have to escape the line breaks at this point.

Comment: I don't know about that, can you make that above code bit more clear for me ?

Comment: How does the CMS inject the values in your JS code?

Comment: <data:post.thumbnailUrl/> CMS is blogger. It gives out the thumbnail URL. If no thumbnail is present, then it generates that thing.

Comment: So you are writing `function1(<data:post.thumbnailUrl/>)`? Or does `<data:post.thumbnailUrl/>` generate the JS as well? Please post the code you are using to generate the above code.

Comment: document.write(function1('<data:post.thumbnailUrl/>','<data:post.url/>')); that's the code.

Comment: Ok. So you have to read in the blogger API how to escape values so that they are save to be used in JavaScript strings. Or maybe those tags are not even meant to be used in such a way. I don't have any experience with blogger.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim):

```
function function1(argument1,argument2)
{
    if(argument1.trim() == ''){
        // do something
    }
}
```

If you're worried about old browsers, you can implement the trim function yourself, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript).

Comment: It seems like the server side is generating invalid JS code, in which case this wouldn't help.

Comment: I tried both trim and replace, but both aren't working.