# Remove space from string and write text in separated line

Tags: javascript, html

i Want to Remove unnecessary space and write content in separated line in textarea.

Ex.

abc

        abcde

   abd

Convert it to:

abc

abcde

abd

Comment: `your_string_as_a_variable.trim()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trim string in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/trim-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Grab the content from the TextArea
2. Loop through the lines and trim each one (removing any empty lines)

CODE:

```
var content = myTextArea.value;

//Split into lines
var lines = content.split( /\r?\n/ );

//Your new content
var newContent = "";

//Loop through all lines
for ( var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++ )
{
    //Trim it first
    var line = lines[ i ].trim();

    //Empty line, remove it
    if ( line === "" ) continue;

    //Add to new content
    newContent += line + "\n";
}

//Save to text area
myTextArea.value = newContent;
```