# Restrict Users from entering only spaces in textbox in c# mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have a view where in textbox user enters a value. 
It may be number, character, special character anything. But I want to validate that user is not allowed to enter ***ONLY spaces***.
User can enter spaces with characters, but ***ONLY spaces*** are not allowed.

For eg.

User can enter 
Name : Stack ""space" Overflow

but user should not be allowed to enter

Name : "space" "space" "space"

Problem is I cant check it server side as my models are DTO defined in another project which is loaded as dll in this one.

Comment: You can use the onkeydown event in javascript. [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp)

Comment: Then do it correctly and use a view model and add the `[Required]` attribute to the property of your view model.

Comment: **RequiredAttribute** works well, as a validation exception is raised if the property is null, contains an empty string (""), or contains only white-space characters.

Comment: @Stephen : My model is in dll, and it does not validate from dll.

Comment: It does not matter where your data model is. Use a view model. Every view especially when editing should have a view model - [What is ViewModel in MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Answer (score 1):

Could you not trim the text and check if the length is greater than zero?

Comment: No.. I have model which sends value to the dll file via object. In this I cant edit each and every value and set again to the object of the model.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
bool b= textBox1.Text.Length>0 && textBox1.Text.Trim().Length==0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a trim function in Javascript. More information can be found here: [Trim string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/trim-string-in-javascript)

Comment: I cant do that. As if I want to enter a value "Stack Overflow" the space in between stack and overflow will be replaced. Also I have already one javascript running that validates if the box is empty.

Comment: `if(string.trim(yourTextBox.text) ==! "") { //Send data to server }`