# Why have two '\' in Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
function trim(str) {

    var trimer = new RegExp("(^[\\s\\t\\xa0\\u3000]+)|([\\u3000\\xa0\\s\\t]+\x24)", "g");

    return String(str).replace(trimer, "");

}
```

why have two '\' before 's' and 't'?

and what's this "[\s\t\xa0\u3000]" mean?

Comment: it is two backslashes because a single backslash has a special meaning in Javascript. Because of this you need to "escape" the backslash

Comment: We should find a better QA for closing as duplicate. This one is too different (but I'm sure it's a duplicate)

Comment: Best I could find @DenysSéguret, I guess they've all been jumped on as too simple..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why have two '\' before 's' and 't'?

In regex the \ is an escape which tells regex that a special character follows.  Because you are using it in a [string literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) you need to escape the \ with \.

> and what's this "[\s\t\xa0\u3000]" mean?

It means to match one of the following characters:

- \s white space.
- \t tab character.
- \xa0 [non breaking space](https://codepoints.net/U+00A0).
- \u3000 [wide space](https://codepoints.net/U+3000).

This function is inefficient because each time it is called it is converting a string to a regex and then it is compiling that regex.  It would be more efficient to use a [Regex literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) not a string and compile the regex outside the function like the following:

```
var trimRegex = /(^[\s\t\xa0\u3000]+)|([\u3000\xa0\s\t]+$)/g;

function trim(str) {
    return String(str).replace(trimRegex, "");
}
```

Further to this \s will match any whitespace which includes tabs, the wide space and the non breaking space so you could simplify the regex to the following:

```
var trimRegex = /(^\s+)|(\s+$)/g;
```

Browsers now implement a trim function so you can use this and use a polyfill for older browsers.  See this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/498995/315017)

Answer (score 5):

You're using a [literal string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).

In a literal string, the `\` character is used to escape some other chars, for example `\n` (a new line) or `\"` (a double quote), and it must be escaped itself as `\\`. So when you want your string to have `\s`, you must write `\\s` in your string literal.

Thankfully JavaScript provides a better solution, [Regular expression literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
var trimer = /(^[\s\t\xa0\u3000]+)|([\u3000\xa0\s\t]+\x24)/g
```

Comment: *hopefully* or *thankfully*?

Comment: @Liam Sorry, I'm still learning English (started about 30 years ago, I think I'll be OK in a few centuries)

Comment: Don't apologise so am I and I've spoke it all my life!