# JQuery string comparison returning incorrect value?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am sending a post request to a PHP script via AJAX like so:

```
$.post("login.php", {u: username,p: password})
    .done(function(response){
        console.debug(response);
        if (response === "0") {
            $("#loginMessage").html("Invalid Username or Password");
        } else {
            $.mobile.changePage("#homePage");
        }
})
```

And `login.php` snippet.  If the login credential fails, I am echoing `"0"`.  I believe this would output a string, since it is in quotes, as opposed to `echo 0;`

```
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0 && password_verify($password,$hashedPassword)) {
        $_SESSION["uid"] = $uid;
    } else {
        echo "0";
    }
```

However, when I enter invalid credentials the comparison `response === "0"` is returning `FALSE`, although when I use `console.debug(response)`, it is showing that it is indeed `0`.

After some of my own fiddling, I found that if I change `response === "0"` to `response == 0`, it correctly evaluates to `true`.

`response === 0` also evaluates to `FALSE`, which confuses me even more.

Can someone explain this a bit for me?

Comment: make sure that (for whatever reason), js isn't converting that `0` from the ajax response into an integer. `0 === "0"` is false in JS, because the types don't match (string v.s. integer).

Comment: That is because `===` checks for equality in value but also in the type of the variable.

Comment: What does `console.log(response.length)` tell you?

Comment: Also, when I changed echo "0" to echo "error"and changed my string comparison to compare response and the string "error", like so: if (response === "error") it would return false, although console.debug(response) would show the string "error".

Very confusing :(

Comment: If you have any whitespaces outside the `<?php ... ?>` delimiters, they will be included in the response. I assume the response you get is actually `0\n` or something similar.

Comment: Felix, very interesting, it says the length of 'response' is 4, when it should be 1.

Comment: Felix, you solved the problem, thank you!!  I had 3 carriage returns at the end of my login.php, now I know to check for that in Sublime Text, thanks :D

Comment: A typical way to prevent such issues is to not have a closing `?>` at all.

Comment: Good tip.  And oh man, this one I'm really glad I asked about on here, literally saved me hours of confusion.  I did have a work around by changing my comparison a bit, but feels good to really know what was causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical reason for this problem is that the response contains whitespace characters. They wouldn't necessarily be obvious in the console, but inspecting `response.length` is one easy way to find out.

Keep in mind that anything outside the `<?php ... ?>` delimiters, also whitespace characters (e.g. line breaks), will be included in the response.

A typical way to prevent trailing whitespace characters is to not have a closing `?>` at all.

---

While you could simply ["trim" the response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/498970/218196) before the comparison, the better solution is to fix the server side script to really just send what you want to send.

Answer (score 0):

Strict equality Operator compares both value and data type. For example, if you compare zero as a string and zero as a number, it returns false. so that is why you see false. Make sure you compare 2 objects with the same type and data when you what to use "Strict equality" (===) otherwise use simple Equality operator (==).