# Critical to solve Contenteditable in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, contenteditable

I am using contenteditable div and span with some icon. when i delete all the characters it takes some spaces in div only in Firefox. In Chrome is working fine.

Code:

```
<div id="test" contenteditable="true">dddddd</div>  **Chrome**
<div id="test" contenteditable="true"> dddddd</div> **FireFox**
```

It occurs when I delete the whole text.

[image]

Span is used for pencil icon.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: @Bram Vanroy added picture.

Comment: @Jaromanda X span is for pencil icon

Comment: I am afraid your question compared to the code, is not clear enough

Comment: It still isn't clear to me what the problem is. Both pictures look the same.

Comment: Is your problem solved by a (JS) [trim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/trim-string-in-javascript)?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug with Firefox. [Bug 74408](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=744408) which is a follow-up bug for [bug 911201](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=911201).

> ...after deleting all text a BR tag (w/ _moz_dirty attribute) is
>   inserted in the `div`...

This also happens when you press space multiple times. The last one inserts a `br`.

The issue is visible here, in the snippet below: *open the dev tools and watch the contents as you delete the text. In Firefox a `br` would be inserted, which is not the case with other browsers.*)

```css
#test {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: monospace;
    background-color: yellow;
    min-width: 50px; font-size: 1.5em;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="test" contenteditable="true">dddddd</div>
<span>&laquo;</span>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/uz0eb092/2/