# Generating an array from based on selected UL LI item - How do you remove a trailing whitespace?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I can't seem to be able to figure out as to why my array would have a trailing white space. The end result after building my array based on selected li items currently looks like this: `1234 ,0123` how can I get the output to be: `1234,0123`?

Here is the Code in question:

```
var arr_numbers = [];
window.onload = function() {

    $(document).bind('click', function(e) {
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        if (!$clicked.hasClass("select")) {
            $(this).find('ul li').hide();
        }
    });

    $(".select").click(function () {
        $(this).find('ul li').toggle();
    });

    $(".select ul li").click(function(e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {                        
                $(this).removeClass('selected');
            }
            else {
                $(this).addClass('selected');
            }

            var c = $(this).parent().find("li.selected").length;

            $(this).closest("div").contents().first()
              .replaceWith((c > 1) ? "(" + c + ")" : $(this).text());
        }
        else {
            $(this).closest("div").contents().first()
              .replaceWith($(this).text());

            var id = $(this).closest('[id]').attr('id');
            $(this).closest('.select').find("ul li").removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    }); 
}


function get_data_array(element) {
    if (element == 'numbers') {
        var data_array_numbers = [];
        var list = $("#numbers ul").find("li.selected")
        $.each(list, function() {
            //alert($(this).data('val'));
            //alert($(this).text());                
            data_array_numbers.push($(this).text());
        });
        alert(data_array_numbers);
    }
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
Numbers
<div class="select" id="numbers">&nbsp;
    <ul>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li data-val="1234">1234</li>
        <li data-val="5678">5678</li>
        <li data-val="0123">0123</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br><br>
Letters
<div class="select" id="letters">&nbsp;
    <ul>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>abcd</li>
        <li>efgh</li>
        <li>ijkl</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br><br>
Fruits
<div class="select" id="fruits">&nbsp;
    <ul>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>apples</li>
        <li>bananas</li>
        <li>oranges</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<br><br>
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="get_data_array('numbers')">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[`jQuery.trim()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)** , to remove the whitespace from the beginning and end of a string

```
data_array_numbers.push(jQuery.trim($(this).text()))
```

Comment: Just a note for developers who are not using jQuery, the `trim()` method is native to the String prototype as of ECMAScript 5: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim. For older browser support, this SO thread is useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/trim-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Pranav's answer you can also use usual string trim:

```
data_array_numbers.push($(this).text().trim());
```

Mind you it doesn't work <=ie8

[w3 reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp)