# Get substring after first space and before first instance of a special character?

Tags: javascript, substring

I am successfully returning a substring before the first instance of a space in a string:

```
var str = "test1 test2 test3 (test4)";
var str_BeforeSpace = str.substr(0,str.indexOf(' '));
// returns "test1"
```

What I'm trying to do next is return a substring that exists after the first space and before the first instance of a "(". In this example, the desired substring is "test2 test3" (with no trailing spaces) ...

Answer (score 2):

Not much different:

```
str.substring(str.indexOf(' ') + 1, str.indexOf('('));
```

If you want to trim leading and trailing spaces, see [Trim string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/498970/218196) .

Comment: In an example string "John B. Doe (Class of 2016)", this function is returning "B. Doe (Class"

Comment: you might want to make it `a = str.indexOf(' '), b = str.indexOf('(', a)`

Comment: Surely you meant `slice`, not `substr`?

Comment: @Bergi: I can never remember whether `substr` or `substring` take the end index. So I guess I mean `substring`. I guess `slice` works too.

Comment: I just always use `slice`. It works the same on arrays :-)