# How to get pure text use JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Html code like this:

```
<div class="form-group row">
     <label id="lb_size" class="col-lg-3 col-form-label">
          <span class="must-have">****</span>
          Size
     </label>
</div>
```

I want to using JQuery get purl text "Size" only .

I Try:

```
$("#lb_size").text()
```

result:  "****Size"

Then I try:

```
$("#lb_size")[0].lastChild
```

result:  "　　　Size　　　"

Finally, I use this code:

```
$($("#lb_size")[0].lastChild).text()
```

result:  "Size"

It's work but it look dirty.

Have a better way to do this ?

Comment: Are you unable to modify the HTML so `Size` is in a span of its own?

Comment: Clone label. Remove all children. Get text. Trim text. Ta-da!!!

Comment: You should also look at [Trim string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/trim-string-in-javascript) for your spaces issue.

Comment: This question was mentioned (as an example) on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361958).

Comment: @Paulpro No, I Can't modify that ...

Comment: @Zenoo Yes, I can use Trim function, but it make a long and dirty look, so I want find a better way

Answer (score -2):

you can you second solution though ...
but you just have to add a little function before this.
`$.trim($("#lb_size")[0].lastChild)`
And you'll be able to get the output 
`"Size"` instead of 
`"     Size    "`

Thanks Ans Happy Coding.