# Angular 4 - Send Data via URL

Tags: angular

I'm trying to send information via URL. The Problem is when i send that data to a component it sends it like **'options/youremailhere@email.com%20'** using this.
So the big question is: How i send it without the "%20"?  Or how can send that information properly

Also this is how i send it:

```
 this.router.navigate(['/options', this.email]);
```

And in my routes:

```
{path: 'options/:email', component: OptionsComponent},
```

Comment: what is in `this.email`? does it have a trailing space?

Comment: it has data from an input form

Comment: you'll likely need to trim it

Comment: Would you be kind to tell me how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/trim-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove extra spaces in your this.email variable:

```
this.router.navigate(['/options', this.email.trim()]);
```