# Get plain text from an RTF text

Tags: c#, .net, rtf

I have on my database a column that holds text in RTF format.

How can I get only the plain text of it, using C#?

Thanks :D

Comment: [Here's another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188545/regular-expression-for-extracting-text-from-an-rtf-string) that discusses the regex way.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Microsoft provides [an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488002.aspx) where they basically stick the rtf text in a `RichTextBox` and then read the `.Text` property... it feels somewhat kludgy, but it works.

```
static public string ConvertToText(string rtf)
{
   using(RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox())
   {
       rtb.Rtf = rtf;
       return rtb.Text;
   }
}
```

Comment: This always annoyed me.  Plus, you have to do this in a STA thread, which usually messes with most program's threading model.

Comment: Having looked at the underlying RichTextBox code... yeah, you're going to want to use it because it's a complex beast.

Comment: i have had issues with this creating a memory leak. Even tho the `RichTextBox rtb` goes out of scope immediately it appears to add to the USER OBJECTs count and never decrement. thus I think it best to wrap it in a using statement.

Comment: Please note that if your RTF inclucludes headers and footers, that text won't be captured by RichTextBox component.

Answer (score 1):

for WPF you can use 
(using Xceed WPF Toolkit) this extension method :

```
public static string RTFToPlainText(this string s)
    {
       // for information : default Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.RichTextBox formatter is RtfFormatter 
        Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.RichTextBox rtBox = new Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.RichTextBox(new System.Windows.Documents.FlowDocument());
        rtBox.Text = s;
        rtBox.TextFormatter = new Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PlainTextFormatter();
        return rtBox.Text;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pure code version, you can parse the rtf yourself and keep only the text bits. It's a bit of work, but not very difficult work - RTF files have a very simple syntax. [Read about it in the RTF spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140284(office.10).aspx).

Comment: yeah, until you get to tables with columns :) But simple bold/italic formatting is easy.