# C# - How to count Words and letters from a .RTF / .TXT File?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, text

The Title says everything..

Searched Google and Stackoverflow and didn't find something similiar..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `.txt` file you can use regexp `\b\w+\b`. It will match all occurrences of words, e.g.:

```
var count = Regex.Matches(input, @"\b\w+\b").Count;
```

To count letters:

```
int count = input.Count(char.IsLetter);
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked fine - to count the words.. Now just need the letters :D

Comment: my SolutioN:  private int GetLetterCount()
        {
            int count = 0;
            StreamReader tr = new StreamReader("hello.txt");
            string text = tr.ReadToEnd();
            foreach (char c in text)
            {
                if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            return count;
        }

Comment: Your method will count digits, punctuation, letters, i.e. all chars excluding whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main()
{
     const string t1 = "To be or not to be, that is the question.";
     Console.WriteLine(WordCounting.CountWords1(t1));
     Console.WriteLine(WordCounting.CountWords2(t1));

     const string t2 = "Mary had a little lamb.";
     Console.WriteLine(WordCounting.CountWords1(t2));
     Console.WriteLine(WordCounting.CountWords2(t2));
}
```

more is [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/word-count)

Answer (score 0):

getting text from rtf - [Get plain text from an RTF text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595865/get-plain-text-from-an-rtf-text)

count words in text - http://www.dotnetperls.com/word-count